# Google Keep search options

Tags: google-keep

I would like to organize my Google Keep notes, using the labels feature.  Is there any way to show only notes without a label?

Comment: Don't remember where I saw this, but I found this tool helpful: https://github.com/darthwalsh/TagTheKeep

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nope, doesn't appear to be so. You should use the "feedback" feature to let them know that that's something you want.

The closest thing available is that you can filter by color. (Color used to be the only way to organize your notes.) If you're consistent about applying a color to items that you've also labeled, you can search for color of "None".

(For what it's worth, the Android app is the same.)

Comment: Great answer! There are 8 colors, so I should be able to use that to get the job done, as long as I limit myself to 8 labels. Oh and I gave feedback to Google too.

Answer (score 2):

You can workaround Keep not having this feature if you're able to automate this workflow with an API like [gkeepapi](https://github.com/kiwiz/gkeepapi):

1. Loop through all notes that aren't archived:

   1. If note has no labels, add label `NO_LABEL`
   2. Or, if note has other labels, remove label `NO_LABEL`
2. Now you can see all notes "without labels" at https://keep.google.com/#label/NO_LABEL

You can try using my implementation on [GitHub](https://github.com/darthwalsh/TagTheKeep). This was inspired by the same question on [Quora](https://www.quora.com/How-do-you-show-only-notes-with-no-label-in-Google-Keep).

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way, but there is sideway: use colors.
Select color which you will left for not labeled notes.
Check that for that colors you don't have notes with labels.
If you have such: re-color them.
For every label you have, select all notes of that label and assign some color. 
Finally, you will have all unlabeled notes grouped by the selected color.